# How can i receive notifications in webview?

Tags: java, android

First I don't mean receiving notifications from OneSignal or Firebase I mean allowing notifications like Google Chrome when you go to website and it ask you to allow receiving notifications. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly that prompt you were saying is just come in website in PC brower/ Mobile Browser or in Android webview.

So, doing in webview, it won't ask you because in mobile there is no such permission you will needs to confirm, by default it will be enabled,

But yes in mobile you do need handle the notification and show in notification tray.

Hope you got the understanding of how it works

Comment: Thanks I'm understanding now. Can you tell me please how to handle notifications from webview or a link to describe it as I searched a lot to find a link that have a way to handle notifications but I can't find.